# how to keep checkedlistbox and a structure in sync

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, list, checkedlistbox

I have declared a structure

```
    Public Structure cList
        Public Name As String
        Public Path As String
        Public isChecked As Boolean
    End Structure
```

And variables of it -

```
    Public sourceList As New List(Of cList)
    Public source As cList
```

And I have a CheckedListBox

What I want to achive is when any of element of checkedlistbox is selected or deselected it must reflact on

```
     sourceList.isChecked = False  'When Deselected
```

or

```
     sourceList.isChecked = True    'When Selected
```

Well this won't work here to achive this and I used a technique here in this ex.

```
    For index = 0 To sourceList.Count - 1
                source = sourceList(index)
                'by this way I can access every source(item) of sourceList
                 source.Name = "test"    
                 any changes
                 sourceList.Add(source)
                 'changes are reflecting to sourceList
            Next
```

To achive sync of checkedListBox.CheckedItems and sourceList.isChecked I written this code

```
      'First making isChecked value to false for every property in sourceList
            For index = 0 To sourceList.Count - 1
                source = sourceList(index)
                source.isChecked = False
                sourceList.Add(source)
            Next
     'Now assigning isChecked=true for Checked items of listbox
            For Each item As String In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
                For index = 0 To sourceList.Count - 1
                    source = sourceList(index)
                    If item = source.Name Then
                        source.isChecked = True
                        sourceList.Add(source)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

but it gives  runtime errors 
Every item selected or deselected didn't reflact on it's corresponding isChecked

Anyone please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work just fine.. The form load event handler is just there to populate the `sourceList` and to bind it to the `CheckedListbox'. This of course populates the`CheckedListBox` with the names of the Items in sourceList

The event handler is the important bit. If the `Checkbox` is already checked, it will uncheck it and mark the item with the same index value in `sourceList`'s property 'isChecked` as false. If the checkbox is already unchecked, it will do the reverse.

```
Public Class cList
    Property Name As String
    Property Path As String
    Property IsChecked As Boolean
End Class

Public sourceList As New List(Of cList)
Public source As cList

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sourceList.Add(New cList With {.Name = "first", .Path = "firstpath", .IsChecked = False})
    sourceList.Add(New cList With {.Name = "second", .Path = "secondpath", .IsChecked = False})
    sourceList.Add(New cList With {.Name = "third", .Path = "thirdpath", .IsChecked = False})
    CheckedListBox1.DataSource = sourceList
    CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
        sourceList.Item(e.Index).IsChecked = False
    Else
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked
        sourceList(e.Index).IsChecked = True
    End If
    MessageBox.Show(sourceList(e.Index).Name & "  " & sourceList(e.Index).IsChecked)
End Sub
```